# Вывод результата работы скрипта

Tags: php

Как связать с этой формой скрипт:

```
<TITLE>Перевод числа из одной системы счисления в другую</TITLE>
<form method="POST" action="">
Десятичное число <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Десятичное число" SIZE=40xBR>
<input type="submit" value=" перевести" name="but">
Двоичное число <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME= "Двоичное число" SIZE=40xBR>
<input type="submit" value=" перевести" name="but">
</form>
```

чтобы при введении числа, выводился результат.

Comment: @andrey26rus, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В action как раз и прописывается путь к скрипту.
При нажатии кнопки браузер на него пошлет введеные данные.
А при пустом "action" можно вычисляющий скрипт написать прямо в этом же файле с формой.